# Regarding WiFi connectivity on my Ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ubuntu-gnome, iwlwifi

I don't know why network strength is too low on wifi signal display though my hotspot device is beside my laptop, whereas it shows full network strength on my mobile which is comparatively far away from my hotspot device!

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723] DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter 
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
  Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
  Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. And is there a real problem besides the signal meter?

Comment: 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
 Kernel modules: rtl8723be
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)